# bash: ./manage.py: Permission denied

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I am trying to keep multiple databases in django settings file.when i have two databases in settings file how can i sync particular db with my app.I am getting this error when trying to sync.

this is my settings file

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {},

'sqlite':
 {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', 
    'NAME': os.path.join(APP_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    'USER': '',
    'PASSWORD': '',
    'HOST': '',                     
    'PORT': '',                      
 },

 'mongodb':
 {
    'ENGINE': 'django_mongodb_engine',
    'NAME': "mydb",
    'USER': '',
    'PASSWORD': '',
    'HOST': '',     
    'PORT': '', 
 }
```

}

when i am trying to execute,

```
[root@localhost mysite]# ./manage.py syncdb --database=sqlite
bash: ./manage.py: Permission denied
```

permissions denied error coming.
Help me if anyone knows.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change the permissions of the file 'manage.py' (make it executable):

```
chmod +x manage.py
```

and then run your script.

Answer (score 3):

You should call it with the python interpreter:

```
python manage.py
```

Or alternatively make it executable then try calling it directly again:

```
chmod +x manage.py
```

Comment: Ya i did,executed "chmod +x manage.py" the command,later i entered, '[root@localhost mysite]# chmod +x manage.py
[root@localhost mysite]# ./manage.py syncdb'
ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.

Comment: That is a different issue. You should check the [settings documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/settings/) for how to properly set your [`DATABASES` setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#databases).

Answer (score 2):

You probably have not granted +x permissions to yourself on `manage.py`. Try running `manage.py` with the Python interpreter explicitly:

```
python manage.py syncdb --database=sqlite
```

Or add the +x flag with `chmod`:

```
chmod a+x manage.py
```